# I need to write a script that it makes association with running services and process in Windows. Put result in hash table

Tags: powershell, devops

My script that it makes association with running services and process in Windows:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Foreach-Object {
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Processes -Value (Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId ) -Passthru
   | Select-Object ProcessId, Name, State, Processes | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"}   }
```

But I don't know how I can put all result in hash table. I would be appreciate if you will help me. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the end would output a list of hash tables:

```
 | foreach-object {
    $hash = @{}
    $object = $_
    $_ | Get-Member -MemberType noteproperty | Foreach-object { 
        $hash.($_.name) = $object.($_.name)
    }
    $hash
}
```

or you could create one hash table with the process ID as the key:

```
$bigHash = @{}
{your code} | foreach-object {
        $hash = @{}
        $object = $_
        $_ | Get-Member -MemberType noteproperty | Foreach-object { 
            $hash.($_.name) = $object.($_.name)
        }
        $bighash.([int]$hash.ProcessId) = $hash
    }
```